# Android program receives wrong data from Java over adb sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, adb

I plugged a phone to my computer via USB. Then I run `adb forward tcp:xxxx tcp:yyyy` to establish a TCP connection. I wrote a C# program to transfer data to an Android program on the phone.

This was all good. But when I replaced the C# program by a Java program, a bug appeared: I sent the number 62, but received 60 or 56. This was not common but very irritating. Roughly one out of 20 tries produced such an error.

The code is complicated so I'm showing it here. Does anybody know what's wrong? Has anyone encountered such situations?

Comment: Is it because of my USB cable?

Comment: I would suggest trying to isolate the issue. For example, try to see if it's something in the way you craft the data you send, or possibly in how you send the data. As it stands, your question is **very** specific and most likely only very few people who've run into a similar issue will be able to help, instead of anyone with some time on their hands.